# cf ic create volume error in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, volume, ibm-cloud-plugin

I need an advice for a trouble with "cf ic create volume" in **bluemix** for a days. I want to know the cause of the failure, whether bluemix's issue or issues in my setup procedure.

The command and response in the Docker Quickstart Terminal on Windows Server 2012R2:

```
     $ cf ic create volume testvol
```

*Error response from daemon:*

```
{
  "incident_id": "1455-1484451778.065-3843854",
  "code": "IC5051E",
  "description": "The image volume could not be retrieved. Verify that the image ID or name is correct.",
  "environment": "prod-dal09",
  "rc": "404",
  "host_id": "177",
  "type": "Infrastructure",
  "name": "ImageNotFound"
}

 FAILED
Command failed
```

Incident report on bluemix:

> RESOLVED: Issues creating container volumes in US South and United Kingdom regions
>
> Users are experiencing issues creating new file shares within the IBM Bluemix Container Service. Because of this, new volume creation is also affected. The engineering teams are working to restore service.
>   UPDATE 2017-01-13 22:10 UTC: the issue has been solved.

```
Updated:    Jan 14, 2017 12:05 AM UTC+0000
Starts: Jan 9, 2017 6:59 PM UTC+0000
Ends:   Jan 13, 2017 10:10 PM UTC+0000
Category:   IBM Containers
Region(s):  us-south
eu-gb
ID: 296975
```

My region is us-south. It looks resolved though my command still failed.

My environment is:

```
cf version 6.22.2+a95e24c-2016-10-27
IBM-Containers   0.8.964 ic IBM Containers plug-in
docker version Client: 
 Version:      1.12.5 
 API version:  1.24 
 Go version:   go1.6.4 
 Git commit:   7392c3b 
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 06:14:34 2016 
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64 
docker version Server: 
 Version:      1.12.6 
 API version:  1.24 
 Go version:   go1.6.4 
 Git commit:   78d1802 
 OS:Windows server 2012R2 on VMWare Workstation 12 Pro
```

Comment: If your issue persists, please open a Bluemix support ticket at https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport. To get responses to your questions about Bluemix system status, post at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/. Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions. Here's a link to the kinds of questions to ask on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are typing the wrong command to create the volume.
The correct command to create a volume is:

```
$ cf ic volume create VOLUME_NAME
```

`cf ic create` will try to create a new container and it is expecting that `volume` is the image name, hence the error you are seeing.

You can see complete docs in the link below:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__d1430e3797

Comment: Thanks, There is an elementary mistake! The output of correct command is "ERROR-SoftLayerAPIError". Then, I create new account on Bluemix and try the command again. It is successful. I use this account.

Comment: If you old account is not working I suggest you open a Bluemix support ticket per Ralph's instructions above. Also could you please accept the answer if solution worked for you?